# jQuery window.execScript fails in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1.On my page I have this function:

```
function loadData() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        async: true,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            start: $('input[name=start]').val(),
            stop: $('input[name=end]').val(),
            week: $('#weekpicker').val(),
            range:$('select[name=date_control]').val(),
            type: 'loaddata'
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr, opts) {
            if (!$('input[name=start]').val() && !$('input[name=end]').val()) {
                bootbox.alert('Select date first!');
                xhr.abort();
                return false;
            }

        },
        success: function(dane) {
            ustawienia = dane.ustawienia;

            // some code here

        },
        error: function(dane) {
            $('button[name=pokaz]').removeAttr('disabled');
            bootbox.alert(dane.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

It work's perfectly on IE>8, FF, Chrome but fails on IE8...
[image]

```
// Evaluates a script in a global context
// Workarounds based on findings by Jim Driscoll
// http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/09/08/eval-javascript-global-context
globalEval: function( data ) {
    if ( data && jQuery.trim( data ) ) {
        // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
        // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
        // rather than jQuery in Firefox
        ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
            var window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
        } )( data );
    }
}
```

How I can fix it to works with IE8 also...

Comment: Why are you calling `xhr.abort()` in the `beforeSend` event? The docs says the request will be cancelled when you `return false`

Comment: xhs.abort() is to stop post ajax call if there is no data selected. Without this ajax call is running. But this is not a problem (without this it also won't work...)

Comment: But `return false` will call this for you.

Comment: `method: 'post',` change it to `type: 'post',` and see what it does.